# How to transfer data from host to virtual machine and back while using Hyper-V

Tags: wmi, hyper-v

There is strange way of information sharing between host and vm in Hyper-V called  [Data Exchange](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn798287(v=ws.11).aspx). It is so slow and uncomfortable. Especially on host machine, cause I need to use WMI to invoke AddKvpItems, RemoveKvpItems, etc. methods...

In my case, OS on VM is Linux, so I could use netlink to read data directly from kernel as it hv_kvp_daemon does...

Is there any way to write data on host machine "directly", without WMI using?

Or more general question: how can I send data with acceptable speed from host to vm and from vm to host?

P.S. Obviously, I could establish network connection, but in my case, virtual machine can be created without network adapters at all.

Answer (score 1):

Use [Copy-VMFile](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn464282.aspx) with PowerShell on the host.  You do need to run Copy-VM file from the host but it does work bidirectionally (you can send or receive data).  File copy is disabled by default but you can enable it on a per-VM basis [instructions here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/virtualization/hyperv_on_windows/user_guide/managing_ics#enable-or-disable-integration-services-using-hyper-v-manager).  You want to enable "Guest Services".

As for making sure file copy is available in your linux distro, the Linux support matrix is a bit complicated [here is the Ubuntu support matrix](https://technet.microsoft.com/windows-server-docs/compute/hyper-v/supported-ubuntu-virtual-machines-on-hyper-v) other distros are available in the left hand nav.  You can also check what is available via available linux drivers [using these instructions](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/virtualization/hyperv_on_windows/user_guide/managing_ics#manage-integration-services-from-guest-os-linux).  Look for hv_fcopy_daemon.

Hope that helps!
Full disclosure:  I work at Microsoft on Hyper-V and those are my docs.  If you can't find the stuff you're looking for let me know :).

Comment: Thanks for answer. Am I correct in assuming that Copy-VMFile uses WMI Msvm_GuestFileService and it's method CopyFilesToGuest?

Comment: Right now I'm looking at [sources of hv_fcopy_daemon](https://github.com/torvalds/linux/blob/master/tools/hv/hv_fcopy_daemon.c) and, unfortunately, don't understand how can I send data back to host...

Comment: You're right, I hadn't used it with Linux in awhile and it does look like we haven't gotten that in.  Sorry about that.  There is using a generation 2 vm and enhanced session mode for shared clipboard but I'm guessing you want something programmatic?

Comment: Yep. C# on Windows and C on Linux. Such a simple task... Just send couple MB of data to VM and back. Also, as I suppose, there is no possibility to share memory pages due to security reasons... At this moment I trying to use KVP for my purposes, and this is a awful.

Comment: It's a little heavy handed for data send and recieve but we do expose a socket connection between win10+ hosts (or server tp3+) and Linux vms running the newest integration services:  https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/virtualization/hyperv_on_windows/develop/make_mgmt_service   Better than kvp :).  It's c only right now (though I understand c# wrappers would make life better).  You can wrap it though, if so inclined.

Answer (score 0):

If you have a spare connected physical hard disk you can share data between the host and a virtual machine. The downside is that you can't share data at the same time so it's a bit clunky, but does allow fast and direct access.

#### On the host

1. Connect the physical hard disk.

   - You can do this whilst the host is running if it's USB, otherwise power off first if it's e.g. an internal SATA disk.
2. Navigate to Disk Management (look for "Create and format hard disk partitions").
3. Right-click the grey part labelled e.g. "Disk 2" and choose Offline.

   - If you don't do this the disk won't appear in the Hyper-V manager.
4. In Hyper-V manager, select Settings for the guest VM.
5. Go to SCSI controller → Hard drive → Add

   - Don't choose "Shared Drive" as this is to share disks between *guests*, so won't achieve what you want.
6. Choose Physical hard disk and select the one you want

   - If this is disabled then the disk is not Offline - see previous steps

#### On the guest

You can then view the disk in the guest machine. Try GParted for example in Linux to see the presence of the disk.

You can remove the disk from the guest then Online in the host if you want to access the data again there.

(As an additional note, if you choose Action → Share in the guest machine this is to [share the virtual machine to move hosts](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/virtualization/community/team-blog/2017/20171113-what-s-new-in-hyper-v-for-windows-10-fall-creators-update#easier-virtual-machine-sharing) rather than data sharing.)