# Sharing a folder between a Window 10 host and a Hyper-V Ubuntu virtual machine

Tags: windows-10, ubuntu-16.04, hyper-v

Is there any working way to share a folder between Windows 10 and a Hyper_v Ubuntu 16.04 virtual machine?

I have a folder on the host with 70GB of data and I have to work with that data on Ubuntu VM, which was created using Hyper-V technology.

I've tried to use WinSCP and other advice found on google, but that all doesn't work.

Comment: This question has now been closed, but see my answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38745762/how-to-transfer-data-from-host-to-virtual-machine-and-back-while-using-hyper-v#77746959

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try using Samba server for sharing folders between two machines. Here is the [wikipedia link](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Samba_(software))

Please explore how to setup samba on corresponding OS and get it going.

Comment: This worked for me, thanks a lot.

Comment: I found this was easier if you want to use a physical rather than network share: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38745762/how-to-transfer-data-from-host-to-virtual-machine-and-back-while-using-hyper-v#77746959